# Add a prefix to base class log messages from a child class

Tags: java

I have a base class (void)method which logs a message. Is it possible to add a prefix for that instance from a child class method?

Example:

let say base class logs `result data`. Can I make it to log `myPrefix: result data` from a child class.

I'm using slf4j

Comment: Features like this are not controlled by slf4j, but by the actual logging library used. So which logging library are you using.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use inheritance and make the parent class abstract forcing the child class to implement a method that will return `myPrefix`:

**ParentClass**

```
public abstract class ParentClass {

public void log(String message) {
    logger.log(getLogMessagePrefix() + message);
}

abstract String getLogMessagePrefix(); }
```

**ChildClass**

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

public final String LOG_PREFIX = "myPrefix";

@Override
String getLogMessagePrefix() {
    return LOG_PREFIX;
}}
```

Comment: but the problem is I don't have access to the source code of the base class. Trying to see if there is any possibility to achieve this via child class

Comment: On this case you can extend the base class and create your own base class with the behavior I mentioned above then your child class will extend the base class and implement the method that will define the log prefix.

Comment: yeah i'm overriding the base function and re-implemented the logic what base had along with my prefix change

Comment: Hi jack, sounds good, does that means that the answer was helpful? If so please mark it as correct, thanks.

Comment: Some logging libraries have features to do this automatically, no need to write this yourself.